# Grabbing the ID attribute of a selected element within my svg-canvas. SVGEDITOR and Methoddraw

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, jquery-svg

I would like to get the id of a selected element within my svg-canvas as a variable to use it within a function.
I would take it that var selected = svgCanvas.getSelectedElems; doesn't pass a particular id.
Any ideas?

Comment: There is no concept of a selected element in SVG - at least I'd feel very stupid if there is.

Comment: I feel stupid because i didn't tag the question as ''svg-edit''. So no worries:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make direct use of selectedElement.id

var elementSel = selectedElement.id;